# Monitor ZFS shrink events

Tags: zfs, proxmox, zfsonlinux

I am using ZFS with Proxmox (debian based). The system has enough free RAM but I am close to hitting the point where ARC shrinking could be trigered.
I would like to monitor these events, or at least have a log where I can see how many times a shrink event has been triggered by ZFS.

Comment: Why do want to monitor for ZFS ARC shrink events?  Are you seeing performance issues correlated with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to monitor `/proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats`. `size` should decrease in case of ARC shrinking. AFAIK there is no build in event logging about ARC shrinking. For more info about arcstats, check out [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1137416/how-can-i-determine-the-current-size-of-the-arc-in-zfs-and-how-does-the-arc-rel).